# injecting unique values into tests when they are run in parallel

Tags: java, junit

A little bit of background:

I am planning to use the Junit framework to execute probes post-deployment. The advantages of using Junit framework rather than writing my own are

- each of the probes are  tests. So, it is intuitive to write each of the probes as a @Test method having their initialization and destroy methods.
- make use of some of the built-in features of JUnit/SpringJunit like Assume, IfProfileValue etc.

The problem I am running into while trying to "leverage" the Junit framework is 
- how do I inject potentially unique values into the tests when the tests are run in parallel?

One of the possible ways I read was using a System property. However, this wouldn't work in my case because the set property could be read by the wrong test or by multiple tests.

I would appreciate your feedback on how to solve this.

Comment: If they are running in the same JVM, you can use a static variable/method (the static keyword makes a variable or method globally-accessible within the same JVM instance).  Remember to make it thread-safe if necessary.

Comment: thanks rob. it definitely is a solution, but, I am trying to avoid "bottlenecks" having to synchronize it. The ideal API would be something like JunitCore.run(clazz, args);

Comment: Can you include some sample code or pseudocode and explain what type(s) of data these potentially unique values are?

Comment: the data that would be injected to the tests would be the hostnames and the ports (based on a selection from the UI) that the tests should run against.

Comment: hostnames and ports are quite simple pieces of information. would it work for you to read them from filesystem?

Comment: @MarcoForberg Nope. it wouldn't. Please refer to my previous comment  "The hostnames and ports are based on user selection."

Comment: yeah i read that and thought it might be possible to store this on disk for testing